# Adding JDK dependencies to jboss 6

Tags: jboss, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror, jboss6.x, java-6

I am using **JBOSS EAP 6.1** using **JDK 1.6**. I have registered all my dependencies as **static** module. I have dependencies on JDK apis. 
During deployment I am faced with following issue:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **javax/crypto/CipherInputStream**
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **org/omg/CORBA/portable/IDLEntity**
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **javax/swing/ImageIcon**

I was able to resolve the above issue by creating a **static module** and adding **rt.jar** and **des.jar** as resources in **moudle.xml** but then I am facing another issue regarding algorithm not found.
**java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithMD5AndDES SecretKeyFactory not available**
  at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.(DashoA13*..)
  at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
  at utilities.algorithm.DesEncrypter.(DesEncrypter.java:49)
  at utilities.algorithm.DesEncrypter.decryptStream(DesEncrypter.java:177)

I want to add include these dependencies from system without creating static module as shown on different forums.
https://community.jboss.org/thread/195182
https://community.jboss.org/message/717881#717881#717881
Can we do it in for EAP 6.1 or its just available for JBOSS AS 7. Can someone please show me an example for EAP 6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to fix the issue. The api included in JDK are exported in different modules and we need to include those modules in our modules as dependences.

For Example: **org/omg/CORBA/portable/IDLEntity** was available in **org.omg.api** module.

Similarly, **javax/swing/ImageIcon** & **javax/crypto/CipherInputStream** was available in   **javax.api**.